# how to add checkbox in javascript append table column

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to inject HTML inside javascript code for creating html table. now i can append the table but i can't create checkbox inside the first table column. if you have any idea about this tell me pls...

i'm trying many HTML code for checkbox but i can't solve the problem.

```
$("#tbody1").html('<tr>'+
    '<td><input type="checkbox" name="alerted"</td>'+
'</tr>')
```

i need to set checkbox in append table column.

Comment: You have a typo (not closing the input). However, I'm confused when you say "append" but are using `html()` (which _replaces_ all the contents of the table, not _appending_ to it). Also, this question has _nothing_ to do with Ajax or PHP. Only add relevant tags.

Comment: Are you trying to append the checkbox in a specific row or just add a row at the bottom of the table?

Comment: i'm trying append the table. and i got it but still i can't add checkbox inside the table column.

Answer (score 0):

You havent closed your tag `..<input type="checkbox" name="alerted"<...`, `>` is missing after "alerted"

Comment: If this is the only problem, it would make it a typo-question and should be closed as that.

Comment: i think this is not the only problem. it doesn't work.

Comment: @deju try to reproduce your problem on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) so we can debug it

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to close input tage inside javascript code . Try this

```
$("#tbody1").html('<tr>'+
                      '<td><input type="checkbox" name="alerted"></td>'+
                  '</tr>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, you can create an element and append.

```js
let bd = document.getElementById('bd');

for(let i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  let tr = document.createElement('tr');
  let td = document.createElement('td');
  td.innerHTML = i;
  tr.appendChild(td);
  bd.appendChild(tr);
  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="bd">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation about what this code solves and how. Answers should be educational, not just code dumps. Also, even though I prefer that people learn vanilla js, the OP seems to currently be using jQuery, so an answer using the same would probably be shorter and easier in the current context.